# React Apollo GraphQL error: getX is not a function

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, sequelize.js, react-apollo

Update: I am really sorry - I made a mistake in the name of the method - I checked through everything so many times and I don't know how I could have missed it for so long! I missed out the word "User" from my getX method reference. It should have been getUserX. (Actually the "User" keyword chosen by the original developers does not really make sense, but that is beside the point.) Stack Overflow does not allow me to delete the question because others have contributed to it, but I don't know if it would be any use to anyone since it was just an oversight.

I am quite new to this development stack (Express.js/React/Apollo/GraphQL) and more of a hacker at this point. I am completely stuck: I used existing code as a blueprint to add new functionality (which is exactly the same, just goes by different names and has its own db tables) and carefully checked that the new code, as well as the db tables were implemented in exactly the same way as for the existing functionality. I am receiving the following error:

> Error: GraphQL error: listing.getTransportLinks is not a function
> GraphQL error: listing.getInTheArea is not a function
> at new ApolloError (D:\path\to\project\node_modules\apollo-client\src\errors\ApolloError.js:34:28)
> at D:\path\to\project\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:325:41
> at D:\path\to\project\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:818:25
> at Array.forEach ()
> at D:\path\to\project\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:815:27
> at Array.forEach ()
> at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (D:\path\to\project\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:812:42)
> at D:\path\to\project\node_modules\apollo-client\src\core\QueryManager.js:747:31

However, the existing functionality also references methods in D:\path\to\project\src\data\types\ShowListingType.js that are not defined explicitly anywhere in the project, e.g...

```js
const ShowListingType = new ObjectType({
  name: 'ShowListing',
  fields: {
    ...
    userSafetyAmenities: {
      type: new List(UserSafetyAmenities),
      resolve(listing) {
        return listing.getUserSafetyAmenities();
      }
    },
    ...
  }
});
export default ShowListingType;
```

The method getUserSafetyAmenities() is not defined explicitly anywhere in the code-base. I have carefully combed through any references to "SafetyAmenities" (non-case-sensitive search) and implemented TransportLinks and InTheArea in exactly the same way (using the same capitalisation standard: sometimes with the first letter small, sometimes capital).

I presume that the method getUserSafetyAmenities() is created dynamically somewhere, but I do not understand why it is not working for getTransportLinks and getInTheArea when I have mimicked SafetyAmenities for these everywhere in the code-base.

Any hints on where to look or how to debug this would be greatly appreciated. As you can probably tell from the file paths, I am on Windows and using VSC.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of object is `listing`? That object is missing a `getUserSafetyAmenities` method. Did you clone `listing` from some other kind of object? Clearly `listing` is defined somewhere otherwise your error message would be along the lines of `cannot access getUserSafetyAmenities property of 'undefined'`.Perhaps is just a simple object and not a member of a class.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but that is just the thing, `getUserSafetyAmenities` and other similar methods called in the file D:\path\to\project\src\data\types\ShowListingType.js under the structure...

`const ShowListingType = new ObjectType({
  name: 'ShowListing',
  fields: {
    ...
    Something {
      type: new List(Something),
      resolve(listing) {
        return listing.getSomething();
      }
    },
    ...
  })
});

export default ShowListingType;`

...do not produce errors (where the `getSomething` is not defined anywhere in the code base.

Comment: ...sorry, I see that line breaks do not work in comments, but hopefully you can still make out the structure? I just found ShowListingType.fields.listPhotos that might give us a hint: This also has `return listing.getListPhotos()`, but immediately under that, commented out is `//return listing.getById(listing.coverPhoto)`. Again though, the `getById` method is not defined anywhere in the project, but it looks like it might be a native method of some node.js module, perhaps? I will investigate the listing object as you suggest, try to reverse-engineer using the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the debugger to stop in an interesting place. This is a sequelize issue! I did not mention sequelize in my question originally because I did not think it was relevant. I thought it was only a version control system for databases and did not realise it was actively used in an application. I did not want to use sequelize migrations since I found them cumbersome. So I presume sequelize just needs to know about the new data and I can do this manually by adding rows to the SequelizeMeta table. I will update my answer with more details once I have it all solved. I hope this question-answer might help others in future, so it is probably worth keeping up.